# The window for selecting a Google account does not open

Tags: python, android, django, webview, django-socialauth

I made my site in Python Django and did authentication through django social auth (googleOauth2) and made a webView application for my site in Android Studio, when authenticating through the WebView application, the window with the choice of account does not open (Select an account), it asks for credentials as login and password. How can I make a window open to select an account?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.